# Specifying URL to ArcGIS Online organization or Portal for ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-web-appbuilder, arcgis-portal

I have downloaded Esri web appbuilder now I want run it but I'm stuck here in the URL.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a Portal or AGOL account?

Comment: i do not know much... i just created account in ESRI and now want to use esri web appbuilder. now how to get the URL to proceed further

Answer (score 5):

You must have either a named user account that belongs to an Organization, or a Developer account to connect Web AppBuilder too. See this help link: https://developers.arcgis.com/web-appbuilder/guide/getstarted.htm specifically this section: `Specify your portal URL`

Note, if you do not have an account, you can sign up for a free trial or setup a developer account:

> If you don't have an ArcGIS account, sign up for an ArcGIS free trial
>   or the ArcGIS Developer Program.

To get an AppID for Web Appbuilder review the next section of the help link above which is titled `Provide an app ID for Web AppBuilder`.

Comment: I solved the URL issue but now stuck in getting the app ID. Help me please. Thanks

Comment: Your next question is literally answered in the next section of the help link I referenced titled `Provide an app ID for Web AppBuilder`